# The Value of LSApplicationLaunchProhibited in payload

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, helper

ERROR ITMS-90639: "Invalid Binary. The value of LSApplicationLaunchProhibited in Payload/
Messages.app/Info.plist can’t change after your app has been released."